# How to get Yahoo Finance (YQL) gzip response?

Tags: yql, yahoo-api, yahoo-finance

Does anyone know how to get the gzip version of a response from YQL?

For example requesting this:

```
http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20*%20from%20yahoo.finance.quotes%20where%20symbol%20in%20(%22AAPL%22)&env=store://datatables.org/alltableswithkeys
```

The response is not gzipped?

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the header "Content-Encoding: gzip" in your request.

However if the server doesn't supports gzip compression method you might not get the same response.
The web server is by no means obliged to use any compression method – this depends on the internal settings of the web server and also may depend on the internal architecture of the website in question.

Comment: Thanks for the info, I have set the Accept-Encoding in the header but maybe the server just doesn't support it. It's a shame because so much bandwidth could be saved

Comment: I checked the URL shared by you and it doesn't supports svgz compression. http://checkgzipcompression.com/